# "Экономическая динамика набрала определенную инерцию" - так можно сказать?

Tags: лексика

Это из сводки новостей:

«По итогам первого полугодия 2015 года [экономическая динамика набрала определенную инерцию](https://news.mail.ru/economics/22949463/?frommail=1), и даже существенное изменение текущих тенденций мало повлияет на результаты текущего года».

Может, тут нечто сугубо экономически-терминологическое таится?

Comment: Ну да, терминологическое...  Просто кому-то невдомёк, что инерция - вторичная характеристика, что её **набрать** невозможно.  Она проявляет себя тем больше, чем больше масса или *момент инерции*.  Динамика, кроме того, ничего не может **набрать**.  Любят же некоторые использовать модные слова!

Comment: Как там было?... "Если рассматривать тенденции парадоксальных эмоций с точки зрения банальной эрудиции и локальной эволюции, то..."

Comment: Виктор, перенесите в ответ - я Вам ЛОшечку вручу! )))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Понятие инерции не является общенаучным. Это понятие физики, точнее механики. Общенаучного понятия нет. Кроме того,это узкое субъективное, методологически не сформированное понятие, не имеющее единого  объективного эталона сравнения. Чего уж говорить о более широком (философском ) толковании инерции. Что является мерой инерции мышления, мерой инерционных процессов в экономике, в развитии общества (инерционность исторических процессов), в биологии, в изменениях видов, заторможенность в психике и пр.? Кстати, в некоторых других направлениях жизнедеятельности людей вводят понятия, несколько похожие на понятие инерции. Например.

•   ИНЕРЦИЯ. Заимств. в XVIII в. из франц. яз., в котором inertie < лат. inertia "бездействие, вялость", суф. производного от iners "неподвижный, вялый". (Школьный этимологический словарь русского язык).

•   РАДЖАС — в индуизме (см.) — сила, энергия; динамическая инерция, инерция движения; качество, или сила Природы (см. Гуны), заставляющая предметы следовать их склонностям, или привычкам движения. В человеке она проявляется как беспокойство тела, возбуждаемость эмоций и течение устаревших мыслей. (Энциклопедия эзотеризма)

В теории относительности инерцию приравнивают к энергии ( " Инерция, сообщённая абстрактному свойству, i-м событием-взаимодействием есть энергия изменения свойства, которая имела какое-то время неизменности до следующего события-взаимодействия ..." А энергию, т.е. силу, набрать можно.

ИНЕРЦИЯ ЭКОНОМИЧЕСКАЯ - свойство экономических систем, объектов сохранять или очень медленно изменять свое состояние; обусловлена, с одной стороны, масштабностью крупных экономических объектов, величиной экономической «массы» и, с другой стороны, инерционностью мышления лиц и органов управления экономическими объектами и процессами.(Современный экономический словарь. 2005)

Экономическую инерцию в узком смысле характеризует коэффициент приростной фондоёмкости (англ. ICOR)- показатель, рассчитываемый как отношение прироста основных производственных фондов к приросту продукции в результате увеличения материализованных капитальных вложений за определенный период

В экономике есть термины "инерция роста, инерция падения". У нас речь идёт об инерции падения, видимо.

```
       «По итогам первого полугодия 2015 года экономическая динамика 
       набрала   определенную инерцию(т.е. энергию, силу), 
       и даже    существенное изменение текущих тенденций мало 
       повлияет на результаты текущего года. На это же указывает 
       динамика   сводного опережающего индекса Центра развития, 
       которая восьмой месяц остается в отрицательной зоне (-3,6%) 
        но пока больше не ухудшается», — отмечает Наталья 
        Акиндинова, руководитель «Центра развития».
```

Экономическая динамика(изменение, падение или рост) набрала инерцию, или силу инерции (СИЛА ИНЕРЦИИ — векторная величина, численно равная произведению массы m материальной точки на её ускорение w и направленная противоположно ускорению).

В русском языке это явление метонимии - инерция = сила инерции. Так что вполне всё грамотно.

Comment: ЭНЕРГИЧНЫЙ  - это полный силы энергии, деятельный,  а ИНЕРТНЫЙ  - это вялый, малоподвижный. Это общее понимание значения этих слов, поэтому в любой науке, при любой терминологии НЕ НАДО ИНЕРЦИЮ НАЗЫВАТЬ ЭНЕРГИЕЙ, иначе метафоричность авторских суждений будет понята неверно или не понята вовсе.

Comment: Вера, Вы о чём? Я же только что сказала, что под инерцией в разных науках понимают разное. Вы о психологии, В физике это разные вещи, а вот в теории относительности они сходятся. Или Вы и в теории относительности знаток? И там СВОИ выводы будете делать?

Comment: Краткая выдержка из работы "Философия относительности или глобальные зависимости естествознания"/ Глава: "СОБЫТИЕ-ВЗАИМОДЕЙСТВИЕ" /....Фактически инерция - есть энергия элементарного относительного изменения данного свойства (равно как и энергия, затраченная на элементарное относительное изменение данного свойства). Инерция, сообщённая абстрактному свойству, i-м событием-взаимодействием естьэнергия изменения свойства, которая имела какое-то время неизменности до следующего события-взаимодействия по свойству определённой природы (размерности) взаимодействия. "

Comment: В философии и экономике  более сходства в суждениях об инерции и энергии, чем в физике.

Comment: Об этом надо спросить специалистов в области философии и экономики (ГДЕ ВЫ, СПЕЦИАЛИСТЫ, ПРИМИТЕ УЧАСТИЕ  В ДИСКУССИИ). А вот в обычном понимании  в суждениях об инерции и энергии больше сходства и с физикой, и, главное, со здравым смыслом.

Comment: Ну Вы даёте, а на филфаке Вы что, философию не учили? А выдержку из теории относительности я Вам привела. Вы с ней не согласны и будете спорить? Ну тогда углубляйтесь в философию и теорию относительности. А я попытаюсь вернуть Вас к вопросу автора: "Может, тут нечто сугубо экономически-терминологическое таится?" Вот именно, терминологическое экономическое (а не физическое), о нём и речь.

Comment: Мне очень трудно смириться с  "набором динамикой инерции", но Вы меня почти убедили! Только я всё равно так говорить не буду, вот. 8-(

Comment: А меня Вы нисколько не убедили (у меня иммунитет против силового давления), и я не только не буду так говорить, но и считаю, что это некорректная форма речи, о чем не мешало бы знать специалистам в области экономики. Мы живем в реальном мире далеко от серхсветовых скоростей, и поэтому надо использовать разумную и понятную терминологию, а не ту, в которой без  учета "энергии элементарного относительного изменения данного свойства" никак не разобраться.

Comment: Галина, да ведь у нас с Вами, по-моему, такой возможности даже говорить нет, мы ж не экономисты. Или Вы экономист?...

Answer (score 2):

**Из физики:** При поступательном движении мерой инертности тела является его масса.  Она измеряется отношением приложенной силы к вызываемому ею ускорению.

Если финансы - это сила, скорость - это темп развития экономики, то **текущая инертность (инерция) в определенный момент времени определяется как их отношение.**

Набрать определенную инерцию - это значит установить зависимость между текущими финансовыми вложениями и темпом развития (получается, что инерция - это ответ системы на финансовые вливания). При большой инерции  даже положительные внешние тенденции не могут  обеспечить заметных изменений.

Comment: Верочка, я думаю... обдумываю. Не укладывается пока. )))

Comment: Галочка, с Вашим появлением  проект стал добрее, как и всё, где Вы появляетесь... Дай Вам Бог здоровья и счастья!

Answer (score 2):

Инерцию (тенденцию обладающих массой тел сохранять состояние покоя или равномерного движения) "набрать" нельзя (это внутреннее свойство), в отличие от скорости или оборотов (при вращательном движении), поэтому лучше обойти такую метафору. Можно сказать, что "*в динамике экономика проявляет инертность*" или "*в (нынешней) экономической динамике просматривается (наблюдается, заметна) инерционность*".

Comment: Alex_ander, а как же формула Эйнштейна, в которой масса зависит от скорости? К тому же эта метафора, а в этом случае  вполне можно представить переменную  инертность. Наша экономика, "набрав" определенную инертность,  движется в определенном темпе в точности по Ньютону - без ускорения, и даже замедлится может. При большой инертности для ее заметного ускорения  потребуются значительное "изменение тенденций в положительную сторону",.

Comment: В формуле Эйнштейна скорость - константа (скорость света, а не объекта). Инерция - свойство объекта, обусловленное его массой; при определённых условиях (например, при попытке изменить текущие параметры движения) это свойство проявляется в замедленной реакции на внешние факторы но само свойство инерционности (консервативности) не меняется, пока экономика остаётся экономикой и напр. не рухнула, потеряв большую часть "массы".

Comment: А мне кажется, что инерционность (консервативность) экономики  определяется ее современной структурой (вот ее-то она и набрала к настоящему моменту). Измените структуру - и инертность будет другая.